# Use QFileDialog to choose a directory and import it into python script

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qfiledialog

I am really on a loss here. My setup is as follows: I create a GUI using QtDesigner and get a `ui.py`. I got a wrapper where I make my modifications to the signals called `ui_module.py`. Then there's my main program where I import the `ui_module.py`. In this main program I want the string of the directory to further use it without any GUI (saving some files).

Here's a MWE:

```
# ui.py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(328, 269)

        # create a button and a label where the file path is displayed
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.savepathButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.savepathButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("savepathButton"))
        self.savepath_label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.savepath_label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("savepath_label"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(savepathButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(savepath_label)
```

Here's the wrapper:

```
# ui_module.py
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog, QAction, QFileDialog
from ui import Ui_Form


class AppWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        # current directory as label text
        self.ui.savepath_label.setText("{}\data".format(os.getcwd().replace("\\\\", "\\")))


        # this is the part where I have to guess what I do
        # how do I update the label text after the button press?
        self.ui.savepathButton.pressed.connect(lambda: self.file_save())



    def file_save(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Choose directory")
        self.ui.savepath_label.setText(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and here's the main program:

```
import ui_module

app = ui_module.AppWindow()
    app.show()
    result = app.exec_()

    if result == 1:
        # how do I get the string of the filepath here?
```

I am not sure where I best specify the QFileDialog signal and how to carry the actual string into my main program. If possible I want to avoid modifying ui.py, because that's the file I get from QtDesigner.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How about `filepath = app.ui.savepath_label.text()`?

Comment: Good point. I was kinda looking for a more direct approach, to somehow get the signal directly from the `QFileDialog`. If there is no other way, I will use this. Thanks.

Comment: No offense, but i think there is a lack of understanding of [Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). In your case it does not make sense using a signal because a) you are callin a static function and b) you do not have any slot to connect it to. To make the above more concise you could write an accesor e.g.: `get_filepath()` that returns the above suggested.

Comment: None taken, I just started looking into PyQt a few weeks ago and I certainly haven't quite grasped the whole idea. The thing you suggested above works, btw. So thank you :)